# How to be able to not to specify the full directory for the subprocess library in python

Tags: python, automation, subprocess

So I have this pretty simple line of code that opens up a .exe file that gets put inside the subprocess.call bracket. However, I always need to specify in full length the location of the .exe file that I'm trying to run. How do I make it so that I don't have to specify it by putting the .py file with the code below inside the same directory with the .exe file that I'm running?

```
import subprocess

def openHC():
    try:
        subprocess.call("R:/Codes/crackingAtHome/crackingAtHomeClient/hashcat.exe")
    except:
        print("something wrong happened")


openHC()
```

I tried to put the .py file in the same directory with no success. I still have to fully specify it for it to run.

Comment: If the `hashcat.exe` binary is in a folder specified in $PATH then you don't need the full path. Other workarounds might include putting the binary and .py file in the same folder, or `chdir()` before you call the subprocess(?).

Comment: That script is supposed to be run on different machines in which the crackingAtHomeClient folder might not be in the same directory. What's the best approach here?

Comment: It shouldn't be your problem to know where `hashcat.exe` is.  That's why path lookup exists: you execute `hashcat.exe`, and it's the job of whoever runs your script to ensure that `hashcat.exe` can be found in a directory on the search path. At most, I would provide a way for the user to specify an exact path via a command-line option or an environment variable.

Comment: You can actually just get CWD then add relative path to it, as long as relative path to executable is same for all machines.

Comment: I am confused. Do you want to put the .py and .exe files in the same directory? If so, the duplicate answer certainly isn't right.

Comment: yes, I want to put them together in the same place for the sake of conveniency. And also because I thought subprocess.call can just look up the programs that's in the same directory as the .py file it's in. Am I wrong to do that? Is there a better way? I just want to share the crackingAtHomeClient folder and be able to run the .py script without any further inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When python runs a script, it usually includes the [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=__file__#file__) variable, naming the .py file being run. You can use that name to find other files in the same directory. This is usually an absolute path, but I don't think its required to be so, so its a good idea to make it absolute anyway. The `pathlib` provides a convenient way to do the calculations.

```
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

try:
    parent_path = Path(__file__).absolute().parent
except:
    # parent path unknown, hope cwd works
    parent_path = Path(".")
    
def openHC():
    try:
        subprocess.call(f'{parent_path/"hashcat.exe"} --help', 
            shell=True)
    except:
        print("something wrong happened")

openHC()
```

Comment: Okay it works but if I try to do subprocess.call([parent_path/"hashcat.exe --help"])
it goes to the exception block instead.

Comment: it should open up hashcat.exe but with the help displayed. It's like a launch option.

Comment: It sounds like you want to run through the shell. I'll try a quick update with help.

Comment: It works like a charm. tysm <3

Answer (score 0):

There are a few concepts to unpack:

### Working directory

When a Python script is run, it usually starts with `cwd` (current working directory) as the `pwd` (present working directory) of the invoking shell.

So assuming we have a script `/tmp/sub/print_cwd.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from os import getcwd

print(getcwd())
```

Then we get the following outputs (with the part before the `$` being the shell's current directory):

```
/tmp/sub$ python3 print_cwd.py
/tmp/sub
/tmp$ python3 sub/print_cwd.py
/tmp
<other location>$ python3 /tmp/sub/print_cwd.py
<other location>
```

### File paths

They can be relative (from cwd) or absolute (from root a.k.a. `/` or `C:\`)

- Relative paths can:

  - go deeper e.g. to `sub/print_cwd.py` from `/tmp`,
  - higher, using `../`, or
  - any combination of the two e.g. to `../../tmp/sub/print_cwd.py` from `/home/user` (up 2 levels to `/`, then back down, into `tmp`)

### PATH

To address the problem of `I don't know where everyone keeps their binaries/exe's`, there is something called PATH (`echo $PATH` to see what yours is).

The tl;dr is that if a binary is in a folder on PATH, you can call it with only the binary name, e.g. `hashcat.exe`

### Putting it together

So what your script (or any shell, for that matter) does, when you specif a filename (binary for execution, but also for file-reads) is check:

- is there a file with this name in my `pwd`?
- is there a file with this name [in a folder] on `PATH`?
- Error: file not found

When you specify an absolute path, it knows exactly where to go, so it only looks there.

### ...What to do in your case?

Options:

1. leave it to the user to ensure `hashcat.exe` is in a folder that is on their PATH, or
2. Accept a location for `hashcat.exe` as a cli-argument to your script, then

   1. call `hashcat.exe` with an absolute path, or
   2. change your pwd to `hashcat.exe`'s location with `os.chdir()`

NOTE: Option #1 was @chepner's suggestion, in an OP-comment.